# Code works on dev server but not live server

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out of a directory exists and if it doesn't throw an error to the user. This is a closed work environment where managers can create folders for employees to upload files to.

The code works on my server as in when I check if a specific folder is available an error isn't thrown however when I use the same code on the live server the error doesn't show and in fact sometimes it throws the error when its not supposed to (existing files).

Here's what my code looks like.

```
if($row['outside'] == 1){ //if job is an outside job folder name will be "jobnum_O"
 if(file_exists(MNT_POINT . "jobs/$job_num" . "_O")){
   print "";
}else{
 print "Warning! Job Folder doesn't exist";
 }
}elseif ($row['usa'] == 0){ //if job is an inside job folder name will be "jobnum"
 if(file_exists(MNT_POINT . "jobs/$job_num/")){
    print "";
 }else{
    print "Warning! Job folder doesn't exist";
}else{
  print "";
}
```

For whatever reason this works well on my test server/site which is as far as I've seen mostly exactly like the live server. The file structure is also the same.

Anyone have a clue why this would be happening ?

Both servers are version 5.4+

Comment: Can you echo something prior to your code, and something else after, just to see that script executes without any error and that your PHP setting is not set to preventing the display of any error messages on screen.

Comment: @ISuthanBala Yes I can echo before and after. I think the script is working fine since a message is displayed on my server when I test for a non existent folder.

Comment: Are you testing it with the same database? Can you echo the values of the `$job_num`, and `$row['outside']` and `$row['usa']` just so that we can be sure the same exact comparison is done on both ends

Comment: @ISuthanBala Goodness gracious I feel stupid, thank you for suggesting that. I am using the same database but I forgot to pull data from those rows in my database in my SQL statement on the live server which explains why the code isn't working on the live server.